# Entity Framework Migrations Testing Migration File

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, migration

I am looking into using EF Migrations for our database.  I would like to create unit tests to verify that the migrations are created correctly. (Aka CreateTable("Foobar") was called.)
I see that the DbMigration class inherits from IDbMigrations, CreateTable is not part of the interface.

Is there a way to verify that CreateTable(...), PrimaryKey(...), etc were called with the correct parameters?

Thanks much

Example of what i would like to test

```
public partial class InitialSchema : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.address_book",
            c => new
                {
                    id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 125, unicode: false),
                    description = c.String(maxLength: 255, unicode: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to test it before updating the server?

Comment: That is correct. I would like to be able to not touch the database at all during the unit test... this will allow us to do continuous integration testing much more easily.

Comment: if you had the sql script for the migration, would that help?

Comment: I don't care really about what is actually sent to the database only that I tried to create it. 
Such as, did i try to create dbo.address_book with an id, name and description column? 
Was the set the primary key to the id?

How EF does this i don't care.. i just want to set up tests that will break the CI Build if the database does not have the proper structure.

Comment: hmm is that a yes then? if you had your sql script you can run your tests there by parsing the text or whatever other method you prefer. if the answer is yes. instead of running `Update-Database` run `Update-Database  -Script -SourceMigration:0`
this will create the script for you without actually running it. hope that helps

Comment: I would prefer not to create an  SQL script.  Parsing and sql script generation may be different each time the `Update-Database -Script` is ran. To do this we would need to get a "golden" copy of the generated sql script and compare it to the test's runtime version.  Or to parse the test's run time version(which would be a nightmare)